# AWS Device Farm Billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

AWS Device Farm gives two [billing](https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faq/#pricing) options - metered and unmetered. After you decide to use unmetered billing by buying an automated testing slot, how does one make sure it is always using that slot and not getting billed for minutes?

Answer (score 2):

You specify `billingMethod = UNMETERED` if you want to use slots in the [`ScheduleRun`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_Run.html#devicefarm-Type-Run-billingMethod) request. If you are using the console or Jenkins, there is a checkbox to specify the billing method.

Please note that the system defaults to `METERED` (pay-per-minute) if you don't explicitly specify this parameter.